# Does anyone know how can I keep the Javascript variable even though the page has been refreshed?

Tags: javascript

Example:

1. In the main page cliked on a button (NEW), the
   page then will using Javascript to
   open a new page in a new window by
   calling redirectPage().
2. In the main page clicked on a button (EXIT),
   then page then will call
   confirmExit(), then
   closeChildWindows() to closed all
   popup new window before redirect to
   another new page.
3. However, the JS variable
   (childWindowHandles) will be always
   reset if I refresh the main page,
   and this cause the page unable to
   close all other popup window before
   relocated while EXIT button being
   clicked

Does anyone know how can I solve this problem? By able to keep the JS variable (childWindowHandles) even the main page being refresh?

```
var childWindowHandles = new Array();

function redirectPage(url)
{
    childWindowHandles[childWindowHandles.length] = window.open(url)
}

function confirmExit(url)
{
    closeChildWindows()
    window.location=url
}

function closeChildWindows() 
{
    for (var loop=0; loop<childWindowHandles.length; loop++) 
    {
        if (!childWindowHandles[loop].closed)
        {
                childWindowHandles[loop].close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global Variable usage on document.ready reload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-document-ready-reload)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use cookies or window.name:) [window.name to store session variables](http://ajaxian.com/archives/whats-in-a-windowname)

Comment: +1: Simple values > `window.name` is a winner. Although there's a catch that (not in latest browser versions thankfully) this value preserves over other domains until it's being reset by any... We have to be careful not to store any volatile data in it.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie) to persist values...

**Edit:** You might find useful a simple object that I use:

*Usage:*

```
// Store a key/value for 1 day:
cookieManager.set('name', 'a value', 1);

// Retrieve a value associated to a key:
var value = cookieManager.get('name');

// Remove a key/value:
cookieManager.remove('name');
```

*Implementation:*

```
var cookieManager = { 
  set: function (name, value, expireDays) { 
    var expireDate = new Date(); 
    expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + expireDays); 

    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + 
      ((!expireDays) ? "" : ";expires="+expireDate.toGMTString()); 
  }, 

  get: function (key) { 
    var start,end; 

    if (document.cookie.length > 0) { 
      start = document.cookie.indexOf(key + "="); 

      if (start != -1) { 
        start = start + key.length + 1; 
        end = document.cookie.indexOf(";",start); 

        if (end == -1) { 
          end = document.cookie.length; 
        }
        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(start,end)); 
      }
    }
    return ""; 
  },

  remove: function (key) {
    this.set(key, '', -1);
  }
}
```

Comment: I was just about to write that.

Answer (score 2):

Per [this post here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194784/which-browsers-support-html5-offline-storage/1195612#1195612), Firefox 3.5, Safari 4, and IE8 support [HTML5 Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/).

Comment: Thats interesting but that seems like more work, hassle, and problems than it would be worth right now than just using a cookie!

Comment: @Breadtruck - true, I wouldn't use it, but it is interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

Or use [PersistJS](http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557) which simplifies your access to whichever back-end storage mechanisms are available. (But cookie-less)

Answer (score 1):

### Use window.name

Positives:

- it will live for the time of browser session - user closes window and it's gone
- it won't put additional traffic on the wire like cookies do
- it works even when cookies are disabled
- at least 2MB space (Opera's limit is this low, other's have 32/64MB)

I also suggest you use javascript object for storing various values and serialize it using JSON and put that string into window.name.

Just make sure you don't persist any vulnerable data inside... For security reasons.

Comment: Are you sure that is not reset after page refresh?

Comment: @Gary: It's not reset. Check [this demo](http://jsbin.com/oWUgUqA/1). When it runs the first time, it sets `window.name` and then it refreshes the page every 2 seconds and displays what's stored in `window.name` that is preserved after refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessionStorage.

Check this out:

[html5_webstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)