# Switch image when page refreshes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, position, switch-statement, image

How to switch an image when the page refreshes, using Javascript?

Let's say I have 2 images:

- ImageA.jpg
- ImageB.jpg

I want to switch those images at locationA and locationB when the page is refreshed.

**Simulation:**

```
- Page Refresh #1
<img id='locationA' src='ImageA.jpg'>
<img id='locationB ' src='ImageB.jpg'>


- Page Refresh #2
<img id='locationA' src='ImageB.jpg'>
<img id='locationB ' src='ImageA.jpg'>


- Page Refresh #3
<img id='locationA' src='ImageA.jpg'>
<img id='locationB ' src='ImageB.jpg'>
```

**[Update #1]**

I try this implementation, but it doesn't work. Could anyone tell me whats wrong with this code?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var images = [];
      images[0] = "I_am_Super_Magnet%21.jpg";
      images[1] = "World_In_My_Hand%21.jpg";

      var index = sessionStorage.getItem('index');
      if(index) index = 0;

      if(index==0)
      {
        document.getElementById("locationA").src=images[index];
        document.getElementById("locationB").src=images[index+1];
        index = index + 1;
      }
      else if(index==1)
      {
        document.getElementById("locationA").src=images[index];
        document.getElementById("locationB").src=images[index-1];
        index = index - 1;
      }
     sessionStorage.setItem('index', index);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id='locationA' src=''>     
    <img id='locationB' src=''>
  </body>
</html>
```

**[Update #2]**

Tested on:

- FF 16.0.1 --> Working!
- IE 8 --> doesn't work

Here is the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function switchImage()
    {
      var images = [];
      images[0] = "I_am_Super_Magnet%21.jpg";
      images[1] = "World_In_My_Hand%21.jpg";

      var index = sessionStorage.getItem('index');

      if(index == null) index = 0;//set index to zero if null

      index = parseInt(index);// parse index to integer, because sessionStorage.getItem() return string data type.

      if(index == 0)
      {
        document.getElementById("locationA").src=images[index];
        document.getElementById("locationB").src=images[index+1];
        index = index + 1;
      }
      else if(index == 1)
      {
        document.getElementById("locationA").src=images[index];
        document.getElementById("locationB").src=images[index-1];
        index = index - 1;
      }
      sessionStorage.setItem('index', index);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="switchImage()">
    <img id='locationA' src='src_locationA'>        
    <img id='locationB' src='src_locationB'>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Thanks to [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/jack) for the
>   clue! and thanks to [Jon Kartago
>   Lamida](https://stackoverflow.com/users/946199/jon-kartago-lamida) for
>   the sample!

Thanks.

Comment: You'd have to maintain state within JavaScript, either with cookie or local storage and toggle it at every page load; server side state management is also possible of course. Lastly, you could randomize the positions (though that would not always result in the same behaviour).

Comment: did you mean like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270468/does-anyone-know-how-can-i-keep-the-javascript-variable-even-though-the-page-has)

Comment: That would sound like a good start; [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage) is another option to think about (more modern browsers support it).

Comment: Thanks for the response and suggestion. I will try it!

Comment: Hi Jack, I try to implemented the code based on [Jon Kartago Lamida](http://stackoverflow.com/users/946199/jon-kartago-lamida) sample, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: If you have a solution that works for you, post it as an *answer*, not an edit to your question. And, don't update the title. The way it works on SO is we know a question is answered when you *accept* an answer(by ticking next to it). You're allowed to do this (after a delay, I think) even with your own answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) comment I create this answer post for my own question.

This is final working solution that I use.

**[Update #3]**

Tested on:

- FF 16.0.1 --> Working!
- IE 8 --> Working!
- Chrome 24 --> Working! (Note: this browser need a little extra effort to make it can read cookie. see this [link](http://www.techtoolblog.com/archives/subdomain-cookies-and-localhost))

Basically the code is still same as Update #2, the different is I use cookie instead of `sessionStorage`. Here is the complete code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function createCookie(name,value,days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }

    function eraseCookie(name) {
        createCookie(name,"",-1);
    }

    function switchImage()
    {
      var images = [];
      images[0] = "I_am_Super_Magnet%21.jpg";
      images[1] = "World_In_My_Hand%21.jpg";

      var index = readCookie('index'); //sessionStorage.getItem('index');

      if(index == null) index = 0;//set index to zero if null

      index = parseInt(index);// parse index to integer, because sessionStorage.getItem() return string data type.

      if(index == 0)
      {
        document.getElementById("locationA").src=images[index];
        document.getElementById("locationB").src=images[index+1];
        index = index + 1;
      }
      else if(index == 1)
      {
        document.getElementById("locationA").src=images[index];
        document.getElementById("locationB").src=images[index-1];
        index = index - 1;
      }
      createCookie('index', index); //sessionStorage.setItem('index', index);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="switchImage()">
    <img id='locationA' src='src_locationA'>        
    <img id='locationB' src='src_locationB'>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag variable in your cookie ( Check [Javascript Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621171/javascript-cookie) SO Question for setting a cookie ).

Every time the page loads, ( in your onload function ) check the value of the flag.

1. Say if value is 0 . Show ImageA in LocationA. Then invert the flag value to 1.
2. Else if value is 1 . Show ImageB in LocationA. Then invert the flag value to 0.

The flag value will be stored in your cookie.

Hope this helps,
Shoubhik

Answer (score 0):

I try to give example according to Jack, using localStorage. Most modern browser have support this. I haven't this this code yet, but more or less should be like this.

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function init(){

var imageA = 'imageA.jpg';
var imageB = 'imageB.jpg';

// state maintaned using localStorage
var toggle = localStorage.getItem('toggle');

if(toggle) toggle = "A"; // if no state yet, initialize

if(toggle == "A"){
toggle = "B";
document.getElementById('locationA').src=imageA;
document.getElementById('locationB').src=imageB;
}else{
toggle = "A";
document.getElementById('locationA').src=imageB;
document.getElementById('locationB').src=imageA;
}
// put state back to local storage
localStorage.setItem('toggle', toggle);
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()">
    <img id='locationA' src=''>     
    <img id='locationB' src=''>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Jon, i have one question. in your code when we set the 'state' value to localStorage for the first time? sorry new to this stuff :)

Comment: And what is 'state' variable for? is that suppose 'var toggle'?

Comment: Yes sorry. It supposed to be toggle.

Comment: Hi Jon, I try to implemented the code based on your sample, but it doesn't work :( could you help me what is wrong with my code? (see my update in original post)

Comment: The javascript should be called after img rendered. You can try to call the script in onload body event or put javascript code at the bottom of body. See my code above for the update.